# Intermittent MySQL connection on Vagrant VirtualBox when Jenkins runs PHPUnit

Tags: mysql, jenkins, phpunit, vagrant, virtualbox

We have a Jenkins CI server that runs our suite of tests on every commit, triggered by a GitHub hook.

We recently moved the suite of tests from running locally on the Jenkins server to running inside a VirtualBox/Vagrant VM. This is to ensure that the test configuration matches the dev environment. This is an Ubuntu 14.04 guest running on Ubuntu 14.04 host.

After moving to the VM model, PHPUnit occasionally fails with no connection to MySQL. The error is `Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1'`.

This error is intermittent, not easily reproducible. That is, if I trigger a new build on Jenkins, it usually succeeds. However, when the new build is triggered by the GitHub hook, it fails more often than manually triggered builds, and sometimes succeeds.

Here's what I tried:

- `sudo service mysql restart` before running `phpunit`
- `sleep 5` between the `mysql restart` and `phpunit`
- Connecting to `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` -- When I tried connecting to `localhost`, I received intermittent errors `Can't connect to MySQL server on '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'`.

Here's the full output of the failed build:

```
sudo service mysql restart
 * Stopping MySQL (Percona Server) mysqld
   ...done.
 * Starting MySQL (Percona Server) database server mysqld
   ...done.
 * Checking for corrupt, not cleanly closed and upgrade needing tables.

sleep 5

sudo service mysql status
 * /usr/bin/mysqladmin  Ver 8.42 Distrib 5.6.23-72.1, for debian-linux-gnu on x86_64

Server version      5.6.23-72.1-log
Protocol version    10
Connection      Localhost via UNIX socket
UNIX socket     /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Uptime:         6 sec    
Threads: 1  Questions: 111  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 761  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 754  Queries per second avg: 18.500

phpunit
PHPUnit 4.6.2 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.    

Configuration read from /vagrant/phpunit.xml    

...........EEE.E.............E............................EEEEE.    

Time: 8.51 seconds, Memory: 135.25Mb    

1) ProcessDatasetsTest::test_process_on_census_fraction
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had intermittent connectivity issues with Mysql on Vagrant, but not precisely related to PHPUnit. Connections were dropping just out of the blue, until I found out there were many boxes running at the same time in virtualbox for the same app. I killed them all, then ran vagrant `global-status --purge` and I had perfect connections again.

Answer (score 1):

We saw a similar issue on a different Vagrant VM -- `Can't connect to MySQL server` -- and it turned out to be a memory issue. The VM was out of RAM. This was fixed by adding or increasing a swapfile on the VM:

```
sudo fallocate -l 1G /swapfile.img
sudo chmod 0600 /swapfile.img
sudo mkswap /swapfile.img
sudo swapon /swapfile.img
```